# What does <xsl:value-of select = “..”/> mean in an xsl file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="xxx/yyy/zzz">
  ...
  <xsl:value-of select = “..”/>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

As `< xsl:value-of select = “.”/ >` means "The current node", I imagine that `< xsl:value-of select = “..”/ >` could mean "The node before the current node", but I'm not sure and I couldn't find anything on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I didn't try it. I was asked to do some modifications on the code and they didn't provide me any XML data to test the template. I'm just trying to understand the behaviour of the template in order to implement the new things. I guess I should make myself some test data to test the template.

Answer (score 0):

`..` is short-hand for `parent::node()`, and so means the parent of the current node. In your case, it will get the text value of the `yyy` node.

So, for example, if your XML looked like this.

```
<xxx>
  <yyy>
    <zzz>A</zzz>
    <aaa>B</aaa>
    <bbb>B</bbb>
  </yyy>
</xxx>
```

Then doing `<xsl:value-of select=".." />`, in a template that matched `zzz`, would actually return "ABB" (with possibly some whitespace included, if the XSLT didn't strip spaces).

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.